# How to know exactly off screen size of the screen in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android , I have a requirement that when activity is loaded one image view fit for  entire screen after 5 second it will be fit exactly off screen for all devices like small ,medium and screens.Because after getting off screen size i want display something in remain screen but i am getting alignment issues in different devices.i have used below code to get the screen size but in Galaxy S3 i got more than off screen size.Please help me.

```
 DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
     getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
     displayHeight=dm.widthPixels;
     displayWidth=dm.heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the the display size in pixels you can use getSize:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

If you're not in an Activity you can get the default Display via WINDOW_SERVICE:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
```

You can get more information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)